# Multiple input on a row in Assembly

Tags: assembly, input, att

How can I implement this C code in Assembly AT&T?

```
scanf("%i %i %i", &a, &b, &c);
```

I need to receive 3 integers on the same row and separated by a space and put them into 3 different registers.

Thank you so much for your help.
AlfonZ

Comment: Can you use the CRT (i.e. the c library)? 32 or 64 bit? On Linux right?

Comment: @knm241 I can't use any library. 32 bit on Linux.

Comment: So you need to implement that ith system calls, right? `strace` prints all system calls made by a program. So write a program calling `scanf()` and run `strace` on it. Then perform these system calls in Assembly.

Comment: @cad I want to understand why I'm doing this or that. I don't wanna compile a C program in a Assembly program. Thank you anyway for you precious help.

Comment: @AlfonZ Executing `strace` will help you understand how it works. It will tell you which system calls are used, so you can read up about them and implement `scanf()` in Assembly. What else do you expect a full answer to do?

Comment: @AlfonZ to read input you will use the syscall 3, `sys_read`. Syscall are not the matter here, is the processing of the input which is done by the CRT. You can check with `strace` but that would be of little to no help (in my opinion).

Comment: @knm241 He wants to implement `scanf()`. He can't use any libraries (including the C library). My conclusion is, he needs to use system calls to implement that in Assembly.

Comment: Thank you @knm241 
So I need to use syscall 3. I think I know how to solve now.

Comment: @cad Agreed. But syscall is just for reading the input, which is the easy part. The whole point of the exercise is to do the string to decimal conversion and store the result to pointers, which is the hard part for the OP as I have taken the question. AlfonZ, I am wrong, do you just need help on how to read a generic string from the user?

Comment: @knm241 Since he wrote "I think I know how to solve now", I suspect the system call was his issue here.

Comment: @knm241 Yes, it's the easy part, but now I know where to start. Anyway, I know how to convert the string read into a decimal number; the problem will be how to read 3 numbers separated from a space and how to recognize the space.

Comment: Well that's the hard part :)

Comment: @knm241 Yes, it is! :)
When I do scanf("%i %i %i, &a, &b, &c), where do the values appear on stack?
I could use leal instruction to take them, or is it a bad idea?

Comment: remember that the 2nd, 3rd and 4th parameters are pointers, so using `leal` will give you a pointer to pointer (which is not bad in this case but requires stack skills). If you set up a standard frame the string will be at `[ebp+08h]`, the first pointer at `[ebp+0ch]`, the second at `[ebp+10h]` and the last at `[ebp+14h]`. Sorry I use intel syntax

Comment: Ok thank you @knm241, I will let you know ;)

Comment: @knm241 See the EDIT on discussion.

Comment: I'd suggest pretending `scanf` doesn't exist, it's not helping you. Instead just focus on this part: "I need to receive 3 integers on the same row and separated by a space." You've apparently figured out that you need to start by reading a string into a buffer. Now figure out how to extract the three integers inside the string in that buffer.

Comment: @Ross Ridge That's the point :)

Comment: My point is that knowing where scanf finds its arguments on the stack is not useful information. Something more useful would be knowing what sort of argument `sToInt` expects.

Comment: @RossRidge sToInt converts a string of characters (whose address is in EAX and delimited by a NULL byte), in a number that is returned in EAX.

Comment: So why then do you expect your example code to work? You're not passing it the address of a string and you're not doing anything with the return value.

Comment: @RossRidge Have you any idea about it?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: I don't need the code, I just need some hints to start with.

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, you need some input on this homework.**

**Disclaimer**
I'm not givin assembly code here, specially because I hate AT&T syntax and because you'll learn more from implementing an high-level code than by reading an assembly source.

---

I suspect it is actually just an exercise where you have to read three unsigned decimal numbers separated by a single space rather than an emulation of `scanf("%i %i %i");`, which behavior is a little bit more elaborate.

I also made a little *C* function that emulated closely `scanf("%d %d %d");` (*note* that the specifier is *%d* and not *%i*) that use no pre-made function.
I don't think you need the full behavior of *%i*.

---

## How your teacher (probably) want you to do it

You have to read a string, you can use the [sys_read](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm) system call to read a string.
Then you have to process the string, here the *C* function (naively coded) you have to code in assembly:

```c
/* This function is given to you */
int sToInt(char* string);

/* This function is what you have to implement */
unsigned int scanf_facsimile2(char* input_string, int* a, int* b, int *c)
{
    char* start = input_string;
    unsigned int numbers_found = 0;
    int temp;
    char last_char;

    for (char *i = input_string; numbers_found < 3; i++)
    {
        last_char = (*i == 0);
        /* If found a space, null terminate the string and convert*/
        if (*i == ' ' || last_char)
        {
            *i = 0;                 /* Null terminate */
            temp = sToInt(start);   /* Convert */

            /* Store result */
            switch (numbers_found)
            {
                case 0: *a = temp; break;
                case 1: *b = temp; break;
                case 2: *c = temp; break;
            }

            numbers_found++;        /* items found +1 */
            start = i + 1;          /* Next string starts at the next char */
        }

        //Last char
        if (last_char)
            break;
    }

    return numbers_found;
}
```

---

## A more close to `scanf("%d %d %d")` version

This version require you to just read a char at a time (can use sys_read with length 1) and can handle newlines and other whitespaces. It also handle negative numbers.

This is easy to extend to full support *%i* or arbitrary number of items to read.
It is also more elegant in my opinion.

```c
/*
   You need to implement this function with the sys_read system call
   To indicate end of input, return a char with value 0 or modify the
   is_eof() function below.
*/
char get_a_char();

/* Tell if white space, can be inlined in assembly version */
char is_white_space(char c)
{
    return c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == ' ';
}

/* Tell if char means EOF, can be inlined in assembly version */
char is_eof(char c)
{
    return c == 0;
}

/* Tell if digit, can be inlined in assembly version */
char is_digit(char c)
{
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

/* Function you have to implement in assembly */
unsigned int scanf_facsimile(int* a, int* b, int* c)
{
    int* pointers[]{a, b, c};           /* Array of pointers to output integers */
    /* The line above emulate how pointers are layout on the stack */

    unsigned int numbers_found = 0;     /* Items found */
    char number_is_negative = 0;        /* Number being scanned is negative */
    char current_char;
    int acc;

    do
    {
        /* Skip white spaces */
        do
        {
            current_char = get_a_char();

            if (is_eof(current_char))
                return numbers_found;
        } while (is_white_space(current_char));

        number_is_negative = 0;
        acc = 0;

        /* Non white space char, check if + or - */
        if (current_char == '+' || current_char == '-')
        {
            number_is_negative = (current_char == '-');
            //Get next char
            current_char = get_a_char();
        }

        /* Convert to number, first digit must be present */
        if (!is_digit(current_char))
            return numbers_found;

        /* Convert to decimal */
        do
        {
            acc = acc * 10 + (current_char - '0');
            current_char = get_a_char();
        } while (is_digit(current_char));

        /* May be here because digits ended or the input ended */

        /* Store the parsed int */
        *pointers[numbers_found++] = number_is_negative ? -acc : acc;
    } 
    while (numbers_found < 3);

    return numbers_found;

}
```